# How can I convert a BigDecimal to a 2-decimal-place string?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to convert a BigDecimal object to a currency value to two decimal places. I don't want any rounding. How can I do it?

None of the following approaches worked:

```
v = BigDecimal("7.1762")
w = BigDecimal("4.2")

v.to_s('2F')            # => "7.17 62"
v.to_s('F')             # => "7.1762"
v.to_s('%0.2F')         # => "0.71762E1"
v.to_s('%0.2f')         # => "0.71762E1"
v.truncate(2).to_s('F') # => "7.17" # This one looks like it worked
w.truncate(2).to_s('F') # => "4.2"  # But it doesn't pad with the trailing zero(es)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about combining [`BigDecimal#truncate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-truncate) and [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25)? :

```
"%.2f" % BigDecimal("7.1762").truncate(2)
# => "7.17"
"%.2f" % BigDecimal("4.2").truncate(2)
# => "4.20"
```

Comment: `"%.2f" % BigDecimal("40000000000000000.199999").truncate(2)` - not sure if relevant to OP, but it is a problem because we are going via `Float`. It does somewhat defeat purpose of using BigDecimal in the first place  though. It is solvable

Comment: Actually this is better: `"%.2f" % BigDecimal("400000000000000.2").truncate(2)` returns `"400000000000000.19"` :-)

Comment: @NeilSlater, How about this? `(BigDecimal("40000000000000000.2").truncate(2).to_s('F') + '00')[/.*\..{2}/]`

Comment: Yes I think that is safe because `BigDecimal#to_s` with `'F'` will always add the decimal point and at least one digit.

Comment: "%.2f" % BigDecimal("100000000000000000000000000").truncate(2)
=> "100000000000000004764729344.00"

Comment: @montrealmike, `(BigDecimal("100000000000000000000000000").truncate(2).to_s('F') + '00')[/.*\..{2}/]`

Comment: @falsetru my point is that with this answer there's also a possibility the numbers will changes before the decimals `...4764729344`

Comment: @montrealmike, I don't get it. I think, it's `%` operator's issue, not BigDecimal itself: `BigDecimal("100000000000000000000000000").to_s('F')` vs `'%f' % BigDecimal("100000000000000000000000000")`

Answer (score 7):

The comments on the accepted answer contain important information.

It's been rightly pointed out that in older versions of Ruby, using `"%.2f" % v` will result in `v` being implicitly converted to a floating-point number, causing potential loss of precision/accuracy - e.g. `"%.2f" % (10**24) == "999999999999999983222784.00"`

You can convert `BigDecimal` to `String` accurately, even in older Rubies, by using `.to_s("F")`.  This returns the number in fixed-point format, with a decimal point followed by zero or more decimal digits.

If you add `"00"` onto the end of the number (to ensure it has two or more decimal digits), then you can then strip it down using a regex like `/.*\..{2}/` (any characters; a decimal point; then two more characters), so it only keeps the first two digits after the decimal point.

```
require 'bigdecimal'
w = BigDecimal("4.2")

 w.truncate(2).to_s("F")                       # => "4.2"
(w.truncate(2).to_s("F") + "00")               # => "4.200"
(w.truncate(2).to_s("F") + "00")[ /.*\..{2}/ ] # => "4.20"
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply formatting with `'%.2f'` should work

```
v = BigDecimal("7.1233")
"%.2f" % v #=> "7.12"

v = BigDecimal("7.1")
"%.2f" % v #=> "7.10"
```

Comment: it rounds the number: `"%.2f" % BigDecimal("7.129") #=> "7.13"`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, although a little verbose:

```
money_amount = BigDecimal.new(100)
money_amount.truncate(2).to_s('F').ljust(money_amount.truncate(0).to_s('F').length + 1, '0')
```